# Bootjack and DQuery internal error. Pub dependency hell

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dart, rikulo, bootjack

I am trying to implement a modal window in my dart application using the Bootjack library within polymer custom elements. No matter what I do my environment keeps throwing an exception. The exception occurs in the DQuery package.

***Internal error: 'package:dquery/src/dquery_impl.dart': error: line 62 pos 24: type parameter 'T': type bounds not yet implemented for mixins
abstract class _DQuery implements DQuery {***

It seems as if all of the correct versions exists too. 
My dependencies are:
name: WidgetTest
description: A sample Polymer application
environment:
  sdk: '>=0.8.10+6 <2.0.0'
dependencies:
  polymer: '>=0.9.1-dev <0.10.0'
  bootjack: '0.6.2'
  browser: any
  dquery: '>=0.5.3+7'
  rikulo_commons: '>=0.7.3'
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points: web/widgettest.html

Running Pub Get runs successfully
Any ideas?? I'm spinning my wheels at this point

Comment: This is a new bug introduced in a recent DQuery update. I've reported this issue on DQuery's Github page. https://github.com/rikulo/dquery/issues/3

Comment: You can try the previous version of DQuery till the package gets fixed.

Answer (score 2):

It is caused by the issue reported here: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=15824

Please stargaze it to follow its status. Meanwhile, please specify `dquery: '0.5.3+7'` to your yaml file. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Thanks Tom! I've now specified bootjack and dquery together. bootjack: '0.6.2' and  dquery: '0.5.3+7' together. I still get the type bounds error. Should I also change the bootjack version? I am most interested in the modal functionality of bootjack. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you try to specify `bookjack: any`? Also, you can check pubspec.lock to see what version of dquery is used.